# An Angular service to provide window and document objects

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

In some components and services I need the `window` and `document`. So I created a small service, that provides these two objects.

**windowAndDocument.service.ts**:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

function getWindow (): any {
  return window;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class WindowAndDocumentService {
  public window = null;

  constructor(@Inject( DOCUMENT ) public document :HTMLDocument) {
    this.window = getWindow();
  }
}
```

This works fine and can be imported into other services.

**some.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { WindowAndDocumentService } from './windowAndDocument.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class SomeService {
  constructor(private wads: WindowAndDocumentService) {}

  soSomething() {
    console.log(this.wads.window);
    console.log(this.wads.document.doctype);
  }
}
```

---

My questions are:

- Is this the optimal way to provide `window` and  `document`?
- Can this be written more concisely? I find it kind of odd, that one variable is injected and the other is pulled from a function call.

---

It's a given that the app runs in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a SOLID code and keep the single responsibility principle, you would need to inject window and document separately.
A clean way is to provide each of them using the `useValue` property of your provider:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
   { provide: "windowObject", useValue: window}
  ]
})
```

as already [answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40222547/532695):
same stuff for the document provider.